# Some images are getting corrupted after upload in php

Tags: php, android, upload

I am trying to upload images to the server and store in a directory called **uploads**, the code works but I noticed that some images (Which are very much viewable from my phone (I am developing an android app)) gets corrupted after upload (I would not be able to view the image in the upload directory/folder).

I couldn't really figure out the common pattern for that error but I noticed it occurs for small .jpg (<100kb) size files.

All other images (jpg, png even webpg gets uploaded).

The php code

```
<?php 
//importing dbDetails file 
require_once 'connect.php';

//this is our upload folder 
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

..............

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //checking the required parameters from the request 
    if(isset($_POST['caption']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
           $sourcePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
           $upload_path = 'uploads/';
           if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $upload_path . $_FILES['image']['name'])){       
          }
   }
```

I have tried everything but the small images of .jpg still gets corrupted after upload.

Comment: dont allow images less than `100kb` to get uploaded

Comment: This piece of code has nothing to do with the problem, you're using PHP just to move the file from temp folder to upload folder. Are you using some function / script / library to modify images?

Comment: Yes I am using android upload service library to upload the files to server in my java.

Comment: If I may ask, why? @dean